# HTML Background disappears on refresh React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am building a website using React.js, and if I am on a page with dynamic query params (i.e. `/group/:groupId`) and I refresh the page, then the background image that is consistent throughout the whole website disappears.  Here is the source code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/master/devicon.min.css">
        <title>Book Blog React</title>

        <style>
        body {background-image:url(hpbackground.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;height:100%; background-attachment: fixed;}

        html {height:100%}

        </style>

        <link href="/static/css/main.03b6e96f.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>



        <div id="root">
        </div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.0fbf6d9f.js">



      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-grid-system';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import CreateAccount from './components/CreateAccount';
import CreateBookGroup from './components/CreateBookGroup';
import AddMembers from './components/AddMembers';
import BookGroup from './components/BookGroup';
import MyGroups from './components/MyGroups';
import CommentPage from './components/CommentPage';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <center>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" history={browserHistory} component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" history={browserHistory} component={Login} />
          <Route path="/createAccount" history={browserHistory} component={CreateAccount} />
          <Route path="/createBookGroup" history={browserHistory} component={CreateBookGroup} />
          <Route path="/addMembers" history={browserHistory} component={AddMembers} />
          <Route path="/bookGroup/:userId" history={browserHistory} component={BookGroup} />
          <Route path="/groups" history={browserHistory} component={MyGroups} />
          <Route path="/post/comments/:postId" history={browserHistory} component={CommentPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>


  </center>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Does anybody know a way that I can work around this issue?  I tried to create a background style and add it to the div that wraps all of my routes in index.js, but when I refresh this, the does not stretch all the way to the bottom of the html screen.  It only extends as far as the items in the component extend.  Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Comment: Have you tried moving the style tag into a css file? I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that your image doesn't use a route and you're trying to reference it in the index.html file. What build tool are you using?